# refreshing listview data getting from server

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I have a listview that gets data from the server. And every time server sends 6 records to the android program and I want to set a refresh button or a time that the listview be updated based on that time . I mean the listview can get the new data from server. Now that I don't have this functionality in my app I should once exit application and enter again to get new data.
This is my class code please tell me how to do it because I am really new to android:

```
public class welcome extends BaseActivity {
TextView loading;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private boolean goNext = false;
private int current_page = 0;
private List<HashMap<String, Object>> all_ads = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView lv;
private List<HashMap<String, Object>> all_city;
private SharedPreferences sp;
private final String SP_KEY = "my_sp";
private final String SP_LBL_UNAME = "username";
private final String SP_LBL_UPASS = "password";
private final String url_cat = "http://afghanamlaak.com/bazaar/get_cat.php";
private String url_ads = "http://afghanamlaak.com/bazaar/get_data.php?page=";
private final String url_ads_by_cat = "http://afghanamlaak.com/bazaar/get_data_by_cat.php?cat=";
private final String url_insert_ads = "http://afghanamlaak.com/bazaar/set_data.php";
private final String url_ads_by_city = "http://afghanamlaak.com/bazaar/get_data_by_city.php?cat=";
private final String url_city = "http://afghanamlaak.com/bazaar/get_city.php";
private Toolbar my_toolbar;
private NewArrayAdapter adp;
private List<HashMap<String, Object>> all_cat;
public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo[] ni = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < ni.length; i++) {
        if (ni[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (isConnected() == false) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(welcome.this);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.internet_error_title);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.internet_error_message);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_exit,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
        );
        alert.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    navigation_drawer myNav = (navigation_drawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    myNav.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcome_layout), my_toolbar);
    /*----------------------------------------------- ads Class ---------------------------------------------------------*/
    sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SP_KEY , MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String s = sp.getString(SP_LBL_UNAME, "");
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRView);

    RecyclerViewDataObject[] items = getMyItems();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getResources()));

    RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter( items , this );

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cat_list.class));
                    }
                    if (position == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), insert_ads.class);

                        intent.putExtra("url", url_insert_ads);

                        String[] id = new String[all_cat.size()];
                        String[] name = new String[all_cat.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < all_cat.size(); i++) {
                            id[i] = all_cat.get(i).get("id").toString();
                            name[i] = all_cat.get(i).get("name").toString();
                        }

                        String[] cid = new String[all_city.size()];
                        String[] cname = new String[all_city.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < all_city.size(); i++) {
                            cid[i] = all_city.get(i).get("id").toString();
                            cname[i] = all_city.get(i).get("name").toString();
                        }

                        intent.putExtra("cat_id", id);
                        intent.putExtra("cat_name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("city_id", cid);
                        intent.putExtra("city_name", cname);
                        intent.putExtra("UNAME", s);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if (position == 2) {
                        sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        sp.edit().clear().commit();
                        Intent in = new Intent(welcome.this, main_page.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    }
                    if (position == 3) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), city_list.class));
                    }
                }
            })
    );
    loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_loading_data);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.welcome_progress_bar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    make_category_list();
    make_city_list();
    clearCache();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ads_list);

     make_all_ads_list();
     lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int i) {
            if (i == 1) {

                if (view.getId() == lv.getId()) {
                    int currentFirstVisibleItem = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    int mLastFirstVisibleItem = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();

                    if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                        // go down
                        if (goNext == true) {
                            goNext = false;
                            make_all_ads_list();

                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), show_full_ads.class);
            intent.putExtra("ads", all_ads.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
    return new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
}

@Override
protected void onAllRequiredPermissionsGranted() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
        sb.append(permission).append("\n");
    }
}

public void make_ads_list_by_city()
{
    try
    {

        DownloadTask dl = new DownloadTask();

        dl.execute(url_ads );

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("NaqibMessage" , "error in ads Class in method make_ads_list_by_city -> " + e.toString());
    }
}

public RecyclerViewDataObject[] getMyItems()
{
    RecyclerViewDataObject[] items = {
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("دسته بندیها" , R.drawable.category) ,
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("آگهی جدید" , R.drawable.share) ,
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("خروج" , R.drawable.logout ) ,
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("دسته بندی بر اساس شهر" , R.drawable.category) ,
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("شرایط درج آگهی" , R.drawable.cond) ,
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("درباره ما" , R.drawable.info ) ,
            new RecyclerViewDataObject("تماس با ما" , R.drawable.contact ) ,
    };

    return items;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
   //clearCache();
}

public void make_all_ads_list() {
    try
    {

        DownloadTask dl = new DownloadTask();

        dl.execute(url_ads + current_page);

        current_page++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("NaqibMessage", "error in ads Class in method make_all_ads_list -> " + e.toString());
    }
}


public void make_ads_list_by_cat()
{
    try {

        DownloadTask dl = new DownloadTask();

        dl.execute(url_ads);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("NaqibMessage", "error in ads Class in method make_ads_list_by_cat -> " + e.toString());
    }
}


private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String temp = "";

        try {
            JSONDownloader jd = new JSONDownloader();

            temp = jd.downloadURL(params[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("NaqibMessage", "error in ads Class in DownloadTask -> " + e.toString());
        }
        return (temp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        ListViewLoaderTask loader = new ListViewLoaderTask();
        loader.execute(s);
        loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}


private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, NewArrayAdapter> {

    @Override
    protected NewArrayAdapter doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        try
        {
            AdsParser parser = new AdsParser();

            if( all_ads.isEmpty() ) {
                all_ads.addAll(parser.parse(params[0]));

                adp = new NewArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.ads_list_row, all_ads);
            } else {
                adp.addAll( parser.parse(params[0]) );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            /*
             * Log.i( "NaqibMessage" , "error in ListViewLoaderTask -> " + e.toString() );
             */
        }

        return adp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(NewArrayAdapter adapter)
    {
        if( lv.getAdapter() == null )
            lv.setAdapter( adapter );
        else
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);

            String imgURL = (String) hm.get("image_path");

            HashMap<String, Object> forDownload = new HashMap<>();

            forDownload.put("image_path", imgURL);
            forDownload.put("position", i);

            ImageDownloaderTask imageDownloader = new ImageDownloaderTask();

            imageDownloader.execute(forDownload);
        }
        goNext = true;
    }
}

private class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {
    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... params) {
        InputStream myStream;

        String imgURL = (String) params[0].get("image_path");
        int position = (Integer) params[0].get("position");

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imgURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            myStream = connection.getInputStream();
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
            File temp = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/image_" + position + "_" + current_page + ".png");
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myStream);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            HashMap<String, Object> bitmap = new HashMap<>();
            bitmap.put("image", temp.getPath());
            bitmap.put("position", position);
            return (bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*
            Log.i("NaqibMessage" , "error in ads Class in ImageDownloaderTask -> " + e.toString());
            */
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        String image = (String) result.get("image");
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adp.getItem(position);
        hm.put("image", image);
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    try {
        File[] f = getBaseContext().getCacheDir().listFiles();

        for (File file : f) {
            file.delete();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("NaqibMessage", "error in ads Class in ClearCache -> " + e.toString());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/) tutorial since you are new to android. You can use Glide and Volley for image download and downloads.

Comment: sorry dude it didn't help me because I don't want to change my code to volley I want to do it the way it is